# Determing if an embedded Linux system runs uClinux

Tags: linux, memory-management, uclinux

I have an ARM Linux system running kernel version 2.4, but I'm not sure if the processor has a memory-management unit, so how can I tell whether the system is running a uClinux kernel or a vanilla Linux kernel? The system does not have `uname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 2.4 supports the [uname](https://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) system call. Try this

```
/*
 * Author: NagaChaitanya Vellanki
 */
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  struct utsname buf;
  if(uname(&buf) != -1) {
    printf("Operating System name: %s\n", buf.sysname);
    printf("Node name: %s\n", buf.nodename);
    printf("Release: %s\n", buf.release);
    printf("Version: %s\n", buf.version);
    printf("Machine: %s\n", buf.machine);
  } else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To compile

```
  gcc -o uname uname.c
```

Sample output on my raspberry-pi

```
./uname                                                                                                     
Operating System name: Linux
Node name: naga-playground
Release: 4.4.11-v7+
Version: #888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016
Machine: armv7l
```

Try these if available as suggested by man-page

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease                                                                              
4.4.11-v7+

cat /proc/sys/kernel/ostype                                                                                 
Linux

cat /proc/sys/kernel/version                                                                                
#888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016
```